# How to add storage settings to Vagrant file?

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

I have created a VM using vagrant and tried to insert a cd, when realized that there is no such device to read it installed.

An option would be to go to my provider UI and through settings add what I need.

I want to know if there is any way to insert this setting (add a cdrom device to VM) into the vagrant file.

My provider is VirtualBox.

**>>UPDATE**

Mixing info from [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html) and [here](http://www.perkin.org.uk/posts/create-virtualbox-vm-from-the-command-line.html), and extending some code example already existing in Vagrantfile I came up with

```rb
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config| 
    ...   
    ...   
    config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
         vb.customize ["storagectl", :id, "--name", "IDEController", "--add", "ide"]
         vb.customize ["storageattach", :id, "--storagectl", "IDEController", "--port", "0", "--device", "0", "--type", "dvddrive", "--medium", "none"]      
         vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--boot1", "disk", "--boot2", "dvd"]
    end
    ...
    ...   
end
```

in the Vagrantfile.

The problem is that now, when attempting to perform `vagrant reload`, I get

```
VBoxManage.exe: error: No storage device attached to device slot 0 on port 0
```

Comment: how about this? https://gist.github.com/leifg/4713995

Comment: Thanks, I will try it. Right now the virtualization I use it's not based on Vagrat, so I will have to install it and check this.

Answer (score 4):

`--medium none` is to telling VirtualBox to delete that DVD, please use `--medium emptydrive`.

See this link https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vagrant-up/Z_KruTTN0vk and medium help：

> `--medium`
>
> Specifies what is to be attached. The following values are supported:
>
> - "none": Any existing device should be removed from the given slot.
> - "emptydrive": For a virtual DVD or floppy drive only, this makes the
>     device slot behaves like a removable drive into which no media has
>     been inserted.